# MongoDB query for documents that contain at least one of the values specified in an array

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a collection in MongoDB that is structured like this:

```
[
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("51bf000a3d489f2df59aa4c6"),
    "courses": ["course1", "course2"]
  }, {
    "_id": ObjectId("52cc789a4df828450c16e52c"),
    "courses": ["course3", "course4"]
  }
]
```

I’d like to be able to query for both documents with an array like `["course1", "course3"]` where `"course1"` matches the first and `"course3"` matches the second document.

Is this possible without a complex query like this?

```
{
  "$or": [
    { "courses": "course1" },
    { "courses": "course3" }
  ]
}
```

Sorry for my poor English!

Comment: If this is a frequent query, be sure to add an index for `courses` to the collection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following query is equal to your:
`db.coll.find({ courses: { $in: ["course1", "course3"] } })`

Comment: Thank you! I read about the `$in` operator but didn’t know it worked on arrays, too.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to further work on your resultset, you can also use aggregates and tweak your result as you wish.

```
db.courses.aggregate([
            {$unwind:"$courses"},
            {$match:{$or:[{courses:"course1"},{courses:"course3"}]}},
            {$project:{_id:0, courses:1}}
    ]);
```

or use $in operator as below:

```
db.courses.aggregate([
        {$unwind:"$courses"},
        {$match:{courses:{$in:["course1","course3"]}}},
        {$project:{_id:0, courses:1}}
        ])
```